# How to create an IOS app that could install without the Apple Store?

Tags: ios, iphone

I find out some app on internet that it installed my phone not through Apple Store. When i clicked "Download App" on the website, it will install automatically on the phone. I wonder why this way is available with Apple Security.

Please, give me a reason. ^_^

Comment: Applications created using Enterprise accounts can be installed directly on any compatible Apple Device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this article:
http://mobiledan.net/2012/03/02/5-options-for-distributing-ios-apps-to-a-limited-audience-legally/

You can do what you want with iOS Developer Enterprise Program -- In-house app distributing.

Answer (score 1):

Compile your Application with Enterprise Account -> Upload on third party site like http://www.diawi.com & share generated link with others

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know about build types then let me tell you there are 3 types of iOS ipa files that can run on iPhone

```
1-Developer Mode 
2-AdHoc Distribution
3-App Store Submission
```

> Developer Mode: it will only run on debugging device
>
> AdHoc : two types of this build
>
> i) Simple account:
>
> for this build you have to add your mobile Udid into the provisioning profile it will only run on that device whose udid is included in the profile.
>
> ii) Premium account:
>
> for this build you don't have to do any thing it will run on every device without adding its udid to provisioning profile.
>
> App Store Submission : for submitting to apple store you have to make this type of build.
>
> //udid means your mobile device id.

Answer (score 0):

Purchase Enterprise account(299 dollars) or simply create ipa and share on TestFlight but  you will still need developer account (99 dollars). In developer account you can register only 100 devices so you cant send ipa to many users. In your case Enterprise account is better. It is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct,
Some apps don't need to go through APP-Store

There is two types of Developer account by Apple,

If you go with "[Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)" (need to pay more), and you have to create Ad-HOC app and upload on 3rd party server, and you can download it from there.